# Pandas Grouper - Why can't it handle numerical columns in order to bin data?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Why can pd.Grouper not handle binning?

Let me illustrate by example.
Consider

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp(year=2020, month=10, day=20, hour=0), pd.Timestamp(year=2020, month=10, day=20, hour=23), freq='1H'), 'v0': np.arange(0,24), 'v1': np.arange(100, 124)})
```

```py
df
    time                v0  v1
0   2020-10-20 00:00:00 0   100
1   2020-10-20 01:00:00 1   101
2   2020-10-20 02:00:00 2   102
3   2020-10-20 03:00:00 3   103
4   2020-10-20 04:00:00 4   104
5   2020-10-20 05:00:00 5   105
6   2020-10-20 06:00:00 6   106
7   2020-10-20 07:00:00 7   107
8   2020-10-20 08:00:00 8   108
9   2020-10-20 09:00:00 9   109
10  2020-10-20 10:00:00 10  110
11  2020-10-20 11:00:00 11  111
12  2020-10-20 12:00:00 12  112
13  2020-10-20 13:00:00 13  113
14  2020-10-20 14:00:00 14  114
15  2020-10-20 15:00:00 15  115
16  2020-10-20 16:00:00 16  116
17  2020-10-20 17:00:00 17  117
18  2020-10-20 18:00:00 18  118
19  2020-10-20 19:00:00 19  119
20  2020-10-20 20:00:00 20  120
21  2020-10-20 21:00:00 21  121
22  2020-10-20 22:00:00 22  122
23  2020-10-20 23:00:00 23  123
```

The typical use case of pd.Grouper is to "bin" time:

```py
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="time", freq="8H")]).agg({'v1': 'sum'})
    
    time                v1
0   2020-10-20 00:00:00 828
1   2020-10-20 08:00:00 892
2   2020-10-20 16:00:00 956
```

I can achieve similar output by using np.digitize:

```py
bins = np.arange(df.v0.min(), df.v0.max(), 8)
df.groupby(np.digitize(df.v0, bins)).agg({'v1': 'sum'})

    v1
1   828
2   892
3   956
```

My question is, why can't i achieve the binning of column v0 with pd.Grouper? So,

```py
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="v0", freq=8)]).agg({'v1': 'sum'})
```

Comment: It is not supported yet, you need datetimes, periods or timedeltas.

Comment: Why? Because it is not intended to do so. `pd.cut` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`pd.Grouper` only supports binning of time objects like datetimes, periods or timedeltas. For other types, `pd.Grouper` will group by unique values.

If you want to group by binned numeric values, `pd.cut` should be your preferred method:

```
bins = np.arange(df.v0.min(), df.v0.max() + 8, 8)
df.groupby([pd.cut(df["v0"], bins, right=False)]).agg({'v1': 'sum'})

# Out:
#            v1
# v0           
# [0, 8)    828
# [8, 16)   892
# [16, 24)  956
```

The  `+ 8` is required for creating the bins, since `np.arange` is right-exclusive. Thus you'd drop the last bin if you do not include the `+8`. `right=False` excludes the right edge from the bins and includes it as the starting point of the next bin.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, I extended my answer.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but how does groupby know which column to bin ? I feel like pd.cut() just gives a mask to which bin every row belongs but groupby is still missing the column ..

Comment: It is grouping by the bins `pd.cut` provides. So yeah, it is effectively using a mask. But the functionality is the same as with column-based groupby. You could f.i. also specify multiple `pd.cut`, f.i. `bins2 = np.arange(df.v0.min(), df.v0.max() + 2, 2)` and `df.groupby([pd.cut(df["v0"], bins, right=False), pd.cut(df["v0"], bins2, right=False)]).agg({'v1': 'sum'})`